# SQL Server query with two conditions

Tags: sql-server

I run a basket analysis and I want to find which category exists only in basket (`order_number`) that has a total of one item. I have two tables,
 `transactions` with the columns `order_number, id_3rd_level, sum_units` 
and `product_categories` with the columns `id_3rd_level, customCategoryDescription`

In `transactions`, `order_number` may be in many rows when the customer has bought many products (with the same or different `id_3rd_level`).

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customCategoryDescription
FROM transactions
    ,product_categories
WHERE transactions.id_3rd_level = product_categories.id_3rd_level
GROUP BY customCategoryDescription
    ,order_number
HAVING sum(sum_units) = 1
```

that returns the `customCategoryDescription` that exists in a basket with `sum(sum_units) = 1` .

I want my query to return which category exists in a basket of one item (like this one) **BUT** this category should be exclusively in baskets with only one item.

For example:

```
Transactions: order_number   id_3rd_level   sum_units
                   1              12            1
                   1              13            1
                   2              12            2
                   3              14            1


Product_category:   id_3rd_level   customCategoryDescription
                          12               "Baby Care"
                          13               "Clothes"
                          14               "Food"
```

I want to return only the `customCategoryDescription` "Food"

How can I change my query to do that?

Comment: Please tag your question properly. Which RDBS you're using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgre SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It isn't exactly clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I add an example.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an other way but the easy way is to use EXCEPT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customCategoryDescription
FROM transactions, product_categories
WHERE transactions.id_3rd_level = product_categories.id_3rd_level
GROUP BY customCategoryDescription, order_number
HAVING sum(sum_units) = 1 

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT customCategoryDescription
FROM transactions, product_categories
WHERE transactions.id_3rd_level = product_categories.id_3rd_level
GROUP BY customCategoryDescription, order_number
HAVING sum(sum_units) != 1
```

Comment: This query returns the customCategoryDescription that exist only in one basket and this customCategoryDescription has sum_units = 1. But in this basket may also exist an item from a different customCategoryDescription.
For example this gives the category "Baby Care". I look for this value in my data and I found that this category exists only in a basket (order_number) but there is a row with the same order_number (so these products are in the same basket) with a different customCategoryDescription

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou - It is impossible to understand your requirements.  This solved the problem as posted.  If you want to solve a different problem then you need to explain it well.  Give example input data, give expected output data.

Comment: Ok sorry, I add an example

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with two levels of aggregation.  But, you can also just use your query, with a twist.

```
SELECT customCategoryDescription
FROM transactions t JOIN
     product_categories c
     ON t.id_3rd_level = c.id_3rd_level
GROUP BY customCategoryDescription
HAVING sum(sum_units) = count(*) and count(*) = count(distinct order_number)
```

This checks that the number of rows is the same as the number of transactions (hence that there is only one transaction per order).  The first condition guarantees the number of units is always one.  You could also add something like `min(sum_units) = 1 and max(sum_units) = 1`, if you prefer.

Comment: This query returns all the customCategoryDescription that exist in a basket with one item BUT at the same time they are in baskets with more than one item.